# How to attach a Listener with Navigation Components within 2 fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm navigating from Fragment A to Fragment B , in Fragment B I need to trigger a callback that is created in Fragment A , I do not want to use a shared viewmodel for this, instead I just want to attach my listener from Fragment A

Currently this is my approach

```
  class FragmentA: MyListener {
    
     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            
             FragmentB().apply {
                this.myListener = this@FragmentA
            }
          myButton.setOnClickListener { findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentB) }
        }

 override fun launchFunction() { ... }
```

Now from my Fragment B I want to trigger this listener in another method that I have but the interface comes as null

```
class FragmentB {

 val myListener: MyListener? = null

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

         myListener.launchFunction()
    }
```

But this is not working, what I suspect is that from FragmentA I apply correctly the listener to an instance of FragmentB that is different from the one that the navController is using to navigate

How can I approach this ?

Thanks

Comment: It is not safe to call any listener on a fragment on the back stack. Is there a reason you're not using the [APIs for returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)?

Comment: I'm not returning a result but instead need to trigger an operation from Fragment A @ianhanniballake

Comment: I think I will go with this https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result and just pop fragment b to execute fragment A method @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code it will work.

```
//Receiver class
class CustomResultReceiver(handler: Handler?, receiver: 
ResultReceiverCallBack) :
ResultReceiver(handler), Serializable {
private var mReceiver: ResultReceiverCallBack = receiver

override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle) {
    mReceiver?.onLaunch(true, resultCode, resultData)
}

interface ResultReceiverCallBack {
    fun onLaunch(action: Boolean, resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle)
}

}



//Fragment A
Class FragmentA:Fragment(),CustomResultReceiver.ResultReceiverCallBack {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentABinding

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
binding = FragmentABinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

binding.dialogButton.setOnClickListener{
findNavController().navigate(
    R.id.action_FragmentA_to_FragmentB,
    Bundle().apply { putSerializable("key", 
 CustomResultReceiver(Handler(requireContext().mainLooper), 
  this@FragmentA))})
}
}

override fun onLaunch(action: Boolean, resultCode: Int, resultData: 
Bundle) {
toast(“Fragment B launch“)
}

} 



//Fragment B 
Class FragmentB:Fragment(){
private lateinit var binding: FragmentBBinding
private var resultReceiver: ResultReceiver? = null

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
binding = FragmentBBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
 arguments.let {
 resultReceiver = arguments?.getSerializable("key") as 
 CustomResultReceiver
}
resultReceiver?.send(1,Bundle())
}
}
```